# django multiple database migrations:how to prevent to create django default tables in each database

Tags: python, django, orm

i have multiple databases and each app bind to one database through router class

```
class DatabaseRouter:
    """
    A router to control all database operations on models in the
    auth and contenttypes applications.
    """
    lawyer_app_labels = {'lawyer'}
    court_app_labels = {'court'}
    type_app_labels = {'type'}

    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        """
        Attempts to read auth and contenttypes models go to auth_db.
        """
        if model._meta.app_label in self.lawyer_app_labels:
            return 'lawyer_db'
        if model._meta.app_label in self.court_app_labels:
            return 'court_db'
        if model._meta.app_label in self.type_app_labels:
            return 'type_db'
        return None

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        """
        Attempts to write auth and contenttypes models go to auth_db.
        """
        if model._meta.app_label in self.lawyer_app_labels:
            return 'lawyer_db'
        if model._meta.app_label in self.court_app_labels:
            return 'court_db'
        if model._meta.app_label in self.type_app_labels:
            return 'type_db'
        return None


    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        """
        Allow relations if a model in the auth or contenttypes apps is
        involved.
        """
        if (
                obj1._meta.app_label in self.lawyer_app_labels or
                obj2._meta.app_label in self.lawyer_app_labels
        ):
            return True

        if (
                obj1._meta.app_label in self.court_app_labels or
                obj2._meta.app_label in self.court_app_labels
        ):
            return True

        if (
                obj1._meta.app_label in self.type_app_labels or
                obj2._meta.app_label in self.type_app_labels
        ):
            return True

        return None


    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
        """
        Make sure the auth and contenttypes apps only appear in the
        'auth_db' database.
        """
        if app_label in self.lawyer_app_labels:
            return db == 'lawyer_db'
        if app_label in self.court_app_labels:
            return db == 'court_db'
        if app_label in self.type_app_labels:
            return db == 'type_db'
        return None
```

each time i try to migrate with --database flag it create app tables successfully but in all app django create default tables such as session and content-type
how can i prevent that
i have 4 databases in setting setup correctly
default for django default tables
and 3 others each for 1 app

Answer (score 0):

i finaly find my own answer
{ 'admin', 'auth',  'contenttypes', 'sessions' }
this is the name of default apps of django
so i included them in

```
base_app_labels = { 'admin', 'auth',  'contenttypes', 'sessions' }
def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
    if app_label in self.base_app_labels:
        return db == 'default'
```

this prevent it to migrate if my db name is not match with default in this app names